# Accessing data in an array within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to access data from an array that is in an object as seen in my code below. I am able to access `main` `temp` okay but not `weather` `main`. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

See link for the data image.

```
let long;
let lat;
let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector(".temperature-description");
let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    let long;
    let lat;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            lon = position.coords.longitude;
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
            const api = `${proxy}api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=d8c99fa56f1fcaaed3c5c9dd0cd52b72`
            fetch(api)
                .then(response =>{
                return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                const {temp} = data.main;
                const {main} = data.weather[0].main;
                // set DOM Elements from the API
                temperatureDegree.textContent = temp;
                temperatureDescription.textContent = main;
            });
        });
    } 
});
```

[Accessing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kekLl.png)

Comment: What do you mean by you can't acces? Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: I see you have a line with `console.log(data);` What is its output? Do you see the fields you want to extract? It could be that your data does not have those fields ...

Comment: Can you please convert the link to text?

Comment: @PayamV yes I get the same data that I have in the link (Accessing Data right below the code) as far as I can tell it does have the fields.

Comment: @periplo. No no errors, nothing appears on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line to either

`const main = data.weather[0].main`

or

`const { main } = data.weather[0]`

What you did was equivalent to accessing `data.weather[0].main.main` which is undefined. Here's the reference page for [object destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) in javascript which can help explain how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

```
main = {
    "weather": [
            {
                "id": 803,
                "main": "clouds",
                "description": "broken clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ]
}

console.log(main["weather"][0]["main"])
```

Prints: `"clouds"`